# Minecraft Modding "Cannot instantiate the type" creatring CreativeTab

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I had a problem yesterday programming a Minecraft Mod.

Here is the code:

Main.java class

```
package com.enricobilla.tempercraft;

import com.enricobilla.tempercraft.creativeTab.MyCreativeTab;

@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.MOD_NAME, version = Reference.MOD_VERSION)
public class TemperCraft {
    public static final MyCreativeTab tabTemperCraft = new MyCreativeTab("tabTemperCraft");
     ... other code ...
}
```

and MyCreativeTab.java class

```
package com.enricobilla.tempercraft.creativeTab;

import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public abstract class MyCreativeTab extends CreativeTabs {
    public MyCreativeTab(String label) {
        super(label);
        this.setBackgroundImageName("tab_tempercraft.png");
    }
}
```

So, my problem is that Eclipse report me "Cannot instantiate the type MyCreativeTab" where I wrote `new MyCreativeTab("tabTemperCraft)` in Main.java and I don't know why...

I've already looked on the Internet but anyone has the same problem.

Can someone help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: Abstract classes can't be instantiated. You need to do one of two things: remove the keyword `abstract` from you `MyCreativeTab` class *OR* create  another class that extends `MyCreativeTab` class and concretizes it. This latter you can instantiate in your `TemperCraft` class.

Comment: @aribeiro Thanks, you answered in 7 minutes!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `MyCreativeTab` is an abstract type and those cannot be instantiated.
You need to remove the `abstract` keyword of your class declaration or subclass it.

See this quote of the [Java Specification:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html)

> A named class may be declared abstract (§8.1.1.1) and must be declared abstract if it is incompletely implemented; such a class cannot be instantiated, but can be extended by subclasses.